# Realtive path from other path in tcl

Tags: path, tcl

I am working in tcl script...

PATH1 "/remote/usXXhomeXX/user001/file_windows/TEST/user.rs"

PATH2 "/remote/usXXhomeXX/user001/Desktop/OUTPUT/GDS_Files"

pwd "/remote/usXXhomeXX/user001/Desktop/LAYOUT"

I want new PATH from my current directory like this 
NEW PATH1 "../../file_windows/TEST/user.rs"
NEW PATH2 "../OUTPUT/GDS_Files"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
file join [pwd] ../../file_windows/TEST/user.rs
```

Etc.

Documentation:
[file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm)

Comment: Thanks @peter-lewerin